# How to render horizontal page layout with multiple frames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

We have a simple app which has a horizontal layout (left hand side panel and content on the right hand side), with a header and footer. So if you click on a certain object on the left hand side, the view is rendered on the right hand side with navigation panel in the header and footer links. The layout actually renders content on the same page itself for any action on the left hand side and the contents of the left hand side will differ based on the section chosen in the header. How should we go about designing the routes in these cases, which differs from the basic navigation where every action is rendered on a different page.

My routes looks like this..

```
  resources :foos do
    resources :foo_bars do
    end
  end
```

I would need to show all foos on the left hand side panel and if the user selects a `foo` it needs to show properties of `foo` and `foo_bars` in a table on the right hand side panel. How will the view look for me and how will the URL at the browser look for me? We will have several tabs at the top and based on that you will show `foos` or similar top level objects

Answer (score 1):

The routes remain the same. You would need to ajaxify your calls.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is:

> how should we go about designing routes

The way you have it is just fine if you want to utilize nested resources, and in your case it seems logical.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Currently, your url will be as follows: `/foos/:foos_id/foo_bars/some_action`

Let me rename these so things make more sense.  Lets say foos is categories, and foo_bars is actions.

Personally, I would override the to_param in the categories model file.

```
to_param
  #return a more readable attribute here
  name
end
```

In this way, your URL would be more closely tied with the names of all the categories on the left side of your page.

So now, if you had a record in the categories table which had the name animal, your URL would look like this: `/categories/animal/actions/some_action`

That seems pretty logical to me.  Make sure in your controller you fetch the record via the proper attribute if you use to_param.

I would apply the same principal to the nested resource as well, then your whole URL would be accurately representing what tab is selected on the page.  If you had a record in actions with the name "running", and you had things setup properly, then you could have your url look similar to: `categories/animal/actions/running`.

You could play around with all the options in your routes file, then use `rake routes` in terminal to see what changes and what your urls will look like before you even touch the browser.

Here are some extra resources for you.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Integration/to_param
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good answer to your question - it all significantly depends on the layout of your application. Besides, there are valid answers here about to_param, and using AJAX, that add important details. But, to give you a head start.

For your views/foos, rewrite your index.html.erb as:

```
<%= render partial: "show_foos", locals: { foos: @foos, selected_foo: nil }%>
```

And your show.html.erb as:

```
<%= render partial: "show_foos", locals: { foos: @foos, selected_foo: @foo }%>
```

In your foos_controller.rb in show method you need to obtain both @foos and @foo, e.g.:

```
@foos = Foo.all
@foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
```

Now, to the fun part. Back to views/foos directory. Create a partial called "_show_foos.erb" (the one that we called both from #index and #show). Do something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= render partial: "show_foos_list", locals: { foos: foos, selected_foo: selected_foo }%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= render partial: "show_foo_props", locals: { selected_foo: selected_foo }%>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please note that's an extremely brute & ugly example that creates a table with two columns: one for the list of foos in the left "panel", the other for displaying the results for the selected foos in the right "panel". In real life use divs and styling. Also, consider pushing the layout to where it belongs - to the appropriate layout file - and using named yields there. But, as I said, a headstart - simple table.

Now, just define the two partials mentioned here. First, the "_show_foos_list.erb" that lists the foos on the left. Assuming each foo has a 'title' attribute, something like:

```
<% foos.each do |foo| %>
  <%= link_to_unless selected_foo && (foo.id == selected_foo.id), foo.title, foo %><br />
<% end %>
```

Second, the foo & foo_bars on the right - "_show_foo_props.erb":

```
<% if selected_foo %>
  # Here display the Foo attributes
  <h2> Foo: <%= selected_foo.title %> </h2>
  <% selected_foo.foo_bars.each do |foo_bar| %>
    # Here display each FooBar that belongs to Foo
    <h3>FooBar <%= foo_bar.title %></h3>
    <%= foo_bar.description %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Again, very crude example. Replace 'title', 'description' with the right sets of parameters, use partials to display FooBars. Do the styling with CSS. Etc, etc, ... Refactor as you see fit.

Talking about the routes. What you get is when you go to your "www.yourapp.com/foos" url is the list of all foos on the left, nothing on the right. Once you press on any foo in the left column, you go to "www.yourapp.com/foos/:id", where :id is the ID of the selected foo (and consider to_param from the other answer here or more advanced techniques to make this part meaningful) and get the list of foos on the left, and the properties of the selected foo and all foo_bars belonging to it on the right.

Hope that helps to start laying out your own implementation based on the rough idea presented here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answers saying Ajax is required are not correct. I have an ancient Perl app (written in 1999) that does this.  Am currently re-implementing in Rails, and it's working fine.  Frames make it particularly easy to allow the data to scroll while the menu stays fixed.

You do need to use HTML4 frames, which are deprecated in HTML5, It's possible to use an IFRAME for the data rendering frame and be HTML5 compliant, but the result is less usable than the FRAME solution in HTML4, at least with some browsers.

As others have said, your routes are fine.

The trick is to use the `target` field in the `form` to direct the Submit response to the rendering frame.  My haml code for the "command" frame is

```
= form_tag admin_menu_path, :method => :put, :target => 'data_frame' do
   ...
```

The rest is just a normal form.  This form remains constant in (my case) the left frame while responses replace each other in the right `data_frame`.

The matching frame HTML is:

```
<frameset cols="360,*">
  <frame name="menu_frame" src="...">
  <frame name="data_frame" src="admin.htm">
</frameset>
```

You would have to use an outer frameset to get the header and footer, but this should be straightforward.

I am ready for comments saying frames are far from best practice.  But for this particular application, they are perfect: simple, understandable, and *extremely* browser independent. E.g. my 1999 Perl generated code ran fine on IE 2.0 and Netscape (the ancestor of Firefox, friends).  And it's still perfect on every modern browser I can find.  Wish Ajax could say the same...

If I've misunderstood your question, I'll happily delete this response.